# Aggregating binary columns into one column with different levels in R

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, data-cleaning

I wonder if someone can help out.
I have the following dataset where an ID has travelled to some cities with no ID duplicates:

```
ID    London   Paris   Rome
1       Yes     No      Yes
2       No      No      Yes
3       No      Yes     Yes
4       No      Yes     No
```

and I'd like to add a column that shows all cities that an ID has travelled to as well as a column showing the number of cities that an ID has travelled to as the following:

```
ID    London   Paris   Rome    All Cities      Count of Cities travelled
1       Yes     No      Yes    London, Rome                2
2       No      No      Yes     Rome                       1
3       No      Yes     Yes    Paris, Rome                 2
4       No      Yes     No     Paris                       1
```

I am trying to use the **dplyr** in **R**

Thank you so much in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(`All Cities` = toString(names(.[-1])[which(c_across(-ID) == 'Yes')]),
         `Count of Cities travelled` = sum(c_across(-ID) == 'Yes'))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Rowwise: 
     ID London Paris Rome  `All Cities` `Count of Cities travelled`
  <int> <fct>  <fct> <fct> <chr>                              <int>
1     1 Yes    No    Yes   London, Rome                           2
2     2 No     No    Yes   Rome                                   1
3     3 No     Yes   Yes   Paris, Rome                            2
4     4 No     Yes   No    Paris                                  1
```

If we need to name the cities:

```
cities <- c('London', 'Paris', 'Rome')

df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(`All Cities` = toString(names(.[, cities])[which(c_across(all_of(cities)) == 'Yes')]),
         `Count of Cities travelled` = sum(c_across(all_of(cities)) == 'Yes'))
```

Comment: thanks! I corrected the typo , Thanks, Ill run the code now and update you

Comment: @arg0nau91 the city columns are not in this order in my data. And there are other columns placed among them. Is there a way to select the city columns or name them instead of using [-1]? Thanks

Comment: See my edit, you can construct a vector of city names and then use it as suggested

Comment: @arg0nau91 Thanks! I don't know why I get this error `could not find function c_across`. I have both **dplyr** and  **tidyverse** installed

Comment: Install the newest version of `dplyr` from CRAN. Just `install.packages('dplyr')`

Comment: @arg0nau91 Just wonder if I can add the word **And** between the name of cities in the column `All Cities` when there is more than one city name? so, for example, the first row will be `London AND Rome`

Comment: You can do `paste(names(.[-1])[which(c_across(-ID) == 'Yes')], collapse = ' AND ')`

Comment: @arg0nau91 thanks! should I add the whole thing inside the mutate statement?

Comment: @arg0nau91 , I am running this code for a bigger data and it is taking hours, just wondering if you a quicker method with Tidy?